# Whenever I deploy new application in aws the old data get's deleted

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Whenever I deploy new updates of application the old data get's deleted, The old data includes the files and those files include pics of the users signed up. I have to deploy the pic but how can I make sure that those pics are not deleted and I can deploy new updates.

Comment: Where was the data being stored?

Answer (score 2):

You **shouldn't store** pictures or any files submitted by your users on Elastic Beanstalk instances.

Not not only because a redeployment of your application can delete them, but most importantly because they run in **AutoScaling Group**. This means that your Elastic Beanstalk instances can get terminated at any time, e.g. due to **scaling activities**. This again would result in lost of any user data.

The good practice is to **de-couple** your storage from your instances. For this, most commonly **S3** is used. This way your users files would persist and were independent of Elastic Beanstalk instance lifeclycle.